# Delphi - increment integer start with zeros

Tags: delphi

How i can increase an integer start with zeros **00000000**, **00000001** , **00000002** ... etc.

```
var
  i:Integer;
begin
  i := 00000000;
  Inc(i);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(i));
```

The problem is the **inc** procedure will trim the zeros on the left.

Output:

```
1
```

Not 00000001.

Comment: It is just formatting / representation = eye candy. 1=01=001=0001=...

Comment: Read the documentation about [`System.SysUtils.Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format)

Comment: Note that `Inc` works on integer types, and that has nothing to do with the output format. Only when you convert an integer to a string (e.g. for display), it matters how you do that, and if you want to show leading zeroes (and how many). `IntToStr` is a rather straightforward function that does not insert any leading zeroes or spaces or other formatting niceties. `SysUtils.Format` provides some of those niceties. Note that `i := 0;` is not different from `i := 00000000;`. You will get the exact same integer.

Comment: Just to be clear: *integers* do not have leading zeroes. *String* representations of numbers can have them, but **integers** do not have leading zeroes. You're formatting a **string** to **display** an integer with leading zeroes. It's important to understand the difference.

Comment: Actually, integers can have leading zero bits. ;-) But I agree that the question seems to indicate the the poster does not know the difference between the binary storage of an integer and its string representation, not in source code, nor in string output representation.

Comment: @Abdulrahman, I suggest you read my [article about memory](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html#memory) (and about pointers as well). Read the first few chapters at least. An integer is not a string, it is a set of bytes that together can store a number of integer values. A string like '00000001' is just one of the possible human-readable representations of such an integer.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I will be enjoyed of reading it all. Thanks for the suggest/sharing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Sir Rufo wrote it is only matter of formatting and probably you are looking for [SysUtils.Format](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.Format)

```
// SysUtils should be in uses;
...
const
  DesiredLen = 8;
var
  i:Integer;
begin
  i := 0;
  Inc(i);
  ShowMessage(SysUtils.Format('%.*d', [DesiredLen, i]))
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `ShowMessageFmt('%.*d', [DesiredLen, i]);`. Of course that does not teach people how to use `Format`. ;-)

Comment: @HeartWare  oops, indeed. My bad :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try this - only one step after Format() -

for i := 1 to NeedLeadingZeros do 
    begin
      if (Result[i] <> ' ') then break;
      Result[i] := '0';
    end;

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".